# Imprimir el resultado de una función en un label a través de un botón

Tags: vb.net

Necesito de vuestra experiencia. Ya que estoy con Visual Basic . net y estoy bastante pez en el tema.

Veréis estoy realizando el típico trabajo de Tragamonedas para la Uni. En el apartado de las combinaciones ya tengo la lógica realizada, pero aún no sé como hacer para que al realizar Click sobre el botón, me capture el resultado de la función y lo imprima en un label.

Es decir:

Click botón -> elegirNumero() Return NumeroAleatorio -> Imprime en label el resultado que dé.

y así tres veces.

¿Me pueden orientar? Gracias!

Comment: Es necesario que ponga el código para ayudarle.

Comment: label.Text = NumeroAleatorio

Answer (score 0):

Es necesario que ponga el código para ayudarle. Pero pues tal vez esto de algo le sirva:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Label1.Text = ""//(Label1)Este sería el label suyo

        Label1.Text = modificarLabel(2, 3)

    End Sub

    Function modificarLabel(num1 As Int32, num2 As Int32)

        Return (num1 + num2).ToString()

    End Function

End Class
```